# Finding connected components in graph (adjA) using DFS

Tags: c++, list, vector, depth-first-search, adjacency-list

I've been searching around the internet today trying to figure out how to run DFS on an adjacency list `vector<list<edge>> adjA`, but I just cannot figure out how to do this correctly.  The best example I could find online was: [Find connected components in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078445/find-connected-components-in-a-graph)
but using his first method does not seem to work and I am not confident enough with unions / sets to try his other method.  This is what I have so far: (disregard `test_vector` and `cc`, I'm focusing on getting the `cc_count` to work)

edge is a struct that contains:

```
struct edge{
    int to; //copy of to_original (dont worry about this it's for a different functionality)
    int w; //weight of edge
    int from_original; //from vertex
    int to_original;  //to vertex
}
```

somewhere in int main:

```
cout << "conn: " << connected(adjA, test_vector) << endl;
```

---

```
int connected(vector<list<edge>> &adjA, vector<short int> &cc){
        int v_size = adjA.size();
        vector<bool> discovered(false,v_size);
        int cc_count = 0;
        for(unsigned int u = 0; u < adjA.size(); u++){
            if(!discovered[u]){
                cout << u << endl;
                discovered[u] = true;
                cc_count+=1;
                dfs(adjA,discovered,cc,cc_count,u);
            }
        }
        return cc_count;
    }
```

---

```
    void dfs(vector<list<edge>>&adjA, vector<bool> &discovered, vector<short int> &cc, int &cc_count,int u){
    for(unsigned int v = 0; v < adjA[u].size();v++){
        if(!discovered[v]){
            cout << v << endl;
            discovered[v] = true;
            dfs(adjA, discovered,cc,cc_count,v);
        }
    }

    }
```

from the line `cout << v << endl;` and `cout << u << endl` it will print showing that it was able to visit every node once.  However, I am incrementing the `cc_count` incorrectly I think.  In this adjacency list:

```
0->[1]->[3]->[5]
1->[0]->[2]->[3]->[4]
2->[1]->[4]
3->[0]->[1]->[4]->[5]
4->[1]->[2]->[3]->[5]->[6]
5->[0]->[3]->[4]->[6]
6->[4]->[5]
```

the program will output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
conn: 7
```

when conn should be 1, since the whole graph is a single component.  I feel like I might be going about this the wrong way.  Is there a change I should do?  Is there a better way to do this using DFS or BFS?

I apologize for the poor formatting, I spent almost an hour just trying to get the stack overflow errors to go away.

[image: graph that adjacency list represents]

graph represented by adjacency list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dfs` method is not looking at the edges at all. I don't know from the question what an `edge` is, but lets just assume it is pair-like (both endpoints).

Then

```
for(unsigned int v = 0; v < adjA[u].size();v++) {
    // do something with v
}
```

should actually be

```
for (auto const & e: adjA[u]) {
    // do something with the endpoint of e other than u
}
```

Comment: ok, so `edge` provides both endpoints. You just need to use one that is not `u`, name it `v` and use you former code.