# Find how many connected groups of nodes in a given adjacency matrix

Tags: java, python, algorithm, graph-theory

I have a list of lists, each list is a node and contains the edges to other nodes. e.g
`[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`

The node has a `1` when it refers to its own position, as well as when it has an edge to another node, and a `0` when no edge exists.

This means that `node 0` (`[1, 1, 0]`) is connected to `node 1`, and `node 2` (`[0,0,1]`) is not connected to any other nodes. Therefore this list of lists can be thought of as an adjacency matrix:

`1 1 0 <- node 0
 1 1 0 <- node 1
 0 0 1 <- node 2`

Adding on to this, whether a node is connected with another is transitive, meaning that if `node 1` is connected to `node 2` and `node 2` is connected to `node 3`, nodes `1` and `3` are also connected (by transitivity).

Taking all this into account, I want to be able to know how many connected groups there are given a matrix. What algorithm should I use, recursive DFS? Can someone provide any hints or pseudocode as to how this problem can be approached?

Comment: Is the question specifically about this graph representation, e.g. about some fancy matrix manipulation that gives the answer? If not, just collect all nodes in a set, than do DFS from some node in the set to get all nodes reachable from that one, remove those from the set, and repeat until all nodes have been reached from some other node.

Comment: Related, probably duplicate: [Find connected components in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21078445/1639625)

Comment: I think your wording implies that **all** transitive relations are **already** represented as `1`s in your adjacency matrix. Am I correct? If so, you can use my algorithm (no need for DFS or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input matrix is guaranteed to describe **transitive** connectivity, it has a peculiar form that allows for an algorithm probing only a subset of the matrix elements. Here is an example implementation in Python:

```python
def count_connected_groups(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    nodes_to_check = set([i for i in range(n)]) # [] not needed in python 3
    count = 0
    while nodes_to_check:
        count += 1
        node = nodes_to_check.pop()
        adjacent = adj[node]
        other_group_members = set()
        for i in nodes_to_check:
            if adjacent[i]:
                other_group_members.add(i)
        nodes_to_check -= other_group_members
    return count


# your example:
adj_0 = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
# same with tuples and booleans:
adj_1 = ((True, True, False), (True, True, False), (False, False, True))
# another connectivity matrix:
adj_2 = ((1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
         (1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
         (1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
         (0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
# and yet another:
adj_3 = ((1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
         (0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
         (1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
         (0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
for a in adj_0, adj_1, adj_2, adj_3:
    print(a)
    print(count_connected_groups(a))


# [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
# 2
# ((True, True, False), (True, True, False), (False, False, True))
# 2
# ((1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
# 2
# ((1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
# 3
```

An **optimized** version of the same algorithm (less readable, but faster and more easily translatable into other languages) is the following:

```python
def count_connected_groups(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    nodes_to_check = [i for i in range(n)]  # [0, 1, ..., n-1]
    count = 0
    while n:
        count += 1
        n -= 1; node = nodes_to_check[n]
        adjacent = adj[node]
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            other_node = nodes_to_check[i]
            if adjacent[other_node]:
                n -= 1; nodes_to_check[i] = nodes_to_check[n]
            else:
                i += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to do this. You can use DFS/BFS or disjoint sets to solve this  problem. Here are some useful links:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-of-islands-set-2-using-disjoint-set/

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Java syntax:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ConnectedGroups {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> adj0 = Arrays.asList("110", "110", "001");
        List<String> adj1 = Arrays.asList("10000","01000","00100","00010","00001");
        List<String> adj2 = Arrays.asList("11100","11100","11100","00011","00011");
        List<String> adj3 = Arrays.asList("10100","01010","10100","01010","00001");

        for (List<String> related : Arrays.asList(adj0, adj1, adj2, adj3)) {
            System.out.println(related);
            System.out.println(count_connected_groups(related));
        }
    }

    private static int count_connected_groups(List<String> adj) {
        int count=0;
        int n = adj.size();
        Stack<Integer> nodesToCheck = new Stack<>();
        nodesToCheck.addAll(IntStream.range(0,n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));

        while (!nodesToCheck.isEmpty()) {
            count++;
            Integer node = nodesToCheck.pop();
            String adjacent = adj.get(node);
            Set<Integer> otherGroupMembers = new HashSet<>();
            for (Integer i : nodesToCheck) {
                if (adjacent.charAt(i) == '1') otherGroupMembers.add(i);
            }
            nodesToCheck.removeAll(otherGroupMembers);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```